# How to place "x" number of objects on the view

Tags: objective-c, ios

If the user provides a number, such as 8, how exactly would I place eight labels onto the view?

For example:

```
int userGivenNumber = textfield.text;

for (int labelNumber=1; i<=userGivenNumber; i++) {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, *previousLabel*.frame.origin.y + 20)];

}
```

How would you get the location of `previousLabel`? Additionally, if the user wanted to edit a label, such as label 3, how would I edit this label?

The problem is that I don't know how many labels they want to place while coding, and I have no way of keeping track of the labels, since they are called `label`. Do you have any ideas? Do you understand what I am asking? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)addLabels {

    CGFloat offset = 0;

    // labels is NSMutableArray property

    labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, offset, 320, 20)];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [labels addObject:label];

        offset += label.frame.size.height;
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Like jerrylroberts said, to access the label array from elsewhere in your code, you should declare it as a property.

Comment: yup, and since the number of labels varies, you can simply set up the array as: NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil]; and add them as you create them not worrying about your limit (much).

Comment: You could also init the frame as `CGRectMake(0, i*20, 320, 20)`

Comment: The only problem with this code is that your mutable array is just a variable and not a property which means it won't be accessible to other areas of the view.  My bet is he'll want to access those labels in other parts of his view

Comment: I do like what you did with the offset though, clever

Answer (score 1):

So you could add the views like so:

```
int userGivenNumber = [textfield.text intValue];

for (int labelNumber=1; i<=userGivenNumber; i++) {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, *previousLabel*.frame.origin.y + 20)];

    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [label release];

}
```

If you wanted to keep track of them you could just create a mutable array as a property and then add each label to the array before you add to the subview;

**Interface**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *addedLabels;
```

**Implementation**

```
@synthesize addedLabels=_addedLabels;

- (void)viewDidLoad

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create your array to hold labels

    NSMutableArray *addedLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    self.addedLabels = addedLabels;

    [addedLabels release];

    // NOW put your code

    int userGivenNumber = [textfield.text intValue];

    for (int labelNumber=1; i<=userGivenNumber; i++) {

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, *previousLabel*.frame.origin.y + 20)];

        [self.view addSubview:label];

        [addedLabels addObject:label];

        [label release];

    }
}
```

Now you can easily access any label you have added if you have the index.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a reference to the location (CGPoint) outside the loop, but update it inside the loop to the current label's location. When you assign the next frame do your operation depending on width and size of the label, and don't forget to update the reference of CGPoint.